# about multiple random number generators with different seeds

Tags: matlab

I have a project that I must use from multiple rand() function with different seed values. How can I do that. do you have any idea?

thanks for your attentions

Ehsan

Comment: The function you are after is [rng](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/rng.html)

Comment: Also RandStream if you're using a slightly older Matlab (or need more control): http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.randstream.html